# Why using WriteConsoleA in mingw has no output?

Tags: windows, mingw

I am trying to compile on mingw a program that prints to console using Windows.h functions. Why do I get no output?
C file:

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main() {
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    WriteConsoleA(out, "hello", 5, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could try to run your program from a command prompt as the window of your program automatically closes.

Comment: Error checking? Are you running it in a console window>

Comment: Okay, I was running it in a MINGW console window and it wasn't working there. I followed your suggestion and run it in cmd.exe and it actually prints. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print to a console your application must be a console application in the first place. A Windows GUI application can

Make sure you linked the application using the `-mconsole` flag.

Also make sure that you are not running the application from somewhere where the output may disappear right away (like an IDE). Instead open a command prompt and run your `.exe` file from there to see the output. Or you could add some code to wait for a key in your code so you can see the output before the window closes automatically.

Comment: Solution: run exe from cmd.exe instead of MSYS2 console

Comment: You should still be able to run a console application from the MSYS2 console and see its output.

Comment: Well it does not, this  is probably due to incompatibility of MSYS2 console with Windows.h library. Normal printf does work.